# delayed_job hooks not executing on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, delayed-job

I am using Delayed Job to deliver emails on Heroku and need to be able to execute various hooks post-processing.  The code below works fine in the development environment, but fails to execute when run on Heroku.

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Handler for Delayed Notifications Hooks
  #- takes in a Delayed::Job object and an optional exception
  def self.processed!(job,exception=nil)
     pay = job.payload_object.args
     # ... do something with the payload object here
  end

  class << self
    def deliver(method,to,ref_obj)
      to.each do |email|
        n = Notification.new(:method => method,:to => email,:delivery=>'email')
        n.obj = ref_obj
        n.save
        # This is where we send the actual email via ActionMailer
        Email.send(method, n).deliver
      end
    end
    handle_asynchronously :deliver

    # Failure handler for Delayed::Job.  
    # Marks our Notification Object as failed
    def error(job,exception)
      Notification.processed!(job,exception)
    end 
    # Success handler for Delayed::Job.  
    # Marks our Notification Object as sent
    def success(job)
      Notification.processed!(job)
    end
  end
end
```

And this is how the call is being made:

```
user = User.find()   # Fetch a user object
Notification.deliver('joined','someone@email.com',user)
```

The email is properly sent via Email.joined, the Delayed Job record is successfully deleted from the database, but the Delayed Job hook `success` is never called.

Again, this works perfectly in development, but fails to work when deployed to Heroku.

Comment: @Richard_Luck I have delayed_job working in development. I'm trying to set up some messaging around job success/errors. I added the `def success` and `def error` per your code above but the job runs fine and nothing happens. How do I get a message on the screen saying the job was done or there was an error so the user is informed?

Comment: @Moosa - given that Delayed Job processes asynchronously, you'll need to implement some form of push notification to the client to inform it of success/failure.  You might want to look at services like [Pusher](http://pusher.com) or [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com).